# Why can't I remove tag name using linq to xml

Tags: c#, xml, linq

why i can't delete the tag name and retain its value if the tag name im going to delete doesn't have a child node

here is the xml file

```
<p>
<li>
      <BibUnstructured>Some text</BibUnstructured>
    </li>
    <li>
      <BibUnstructured>another text</BibUnstructured>
    </li>
</p>
```

and this is must be the output

```
<p>
<li>
      Some text
    </li>
    <li>
      another text
    </li>
</p>
```

and here is my code as of now

```
XElement rootBook = XElement.Load("try.xml");
            IEnumerable<XElement> Book =
                from el in rootBook.Descendants("BibUnstructured").ToList()
                select el;
            foreach (XElement el in Book)
            {
                if (el.HasElements)
                {
                    el.ReplaceWith(el.Elements());
                }
                Console.WriteLine(el);
            }
            Console.WriteLine(rootBook.ToString());
```

if i remove the if statement it delete the tag name and its content

Comment: BibUnstructured doesn't have any child elements, only innertext.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your `BibUnstructured` elements don't have child *elements*, but the do have child *nodes* (text nodes, in this case).  Try this:

```
foreach (var book in doc.Descendants("BibUnstructured").ToList())
{
    if (book.Nodes().Any())
    {
        book.ReplaceWith(book.Nodes());
    }
}
```

See [this fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/0l5k39) for a working demo.

Answer (score 1):

***Charles*** already explained why it is not working, alternatively you could also do this.

```
    XElement element = XElement.Load("try.xml");

    element.Descendants("li").ToList().ForEach(x=> {            
        var item = x.Element("BibUnstructured");

        if(item != null)
        {
            x.Add(item.Value);      
            item.Remove();
        } 
    });
```

Check this [`Demo`](https://dotnetfiddle.net/hGBWBe)

Answer (score 0):

You have to set the value of parent node to the value of the child node you are going to delete.
Try the following:

```
 XElement rootBook = XElement.Load("try.xml");
        IEnumerable<XElement> Book =
            from el in rootBook.Descendants("BibUnstructured").ToList()
            select el;
        foreach (XElement el in Book)
        {
            if (!el.HasElements)
            {
                XElement parent= el.Parent;
                string value=el.Value;
                el.Remove();
                parent.Value=value;
                Console.WriteLine(parent);
            }

        }
        Console.WriteLine(rootBook.ToString());
```

And the output is:

```
<li>Some text</li>
<li>another text</li>
<p>
<li>Some text</li>
<li>another text</li>
</p>
```